# Inner while loop not working.. it limit to only one row

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inner while loop not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680530/inner-while-loop-not-working)

This is a code pinch from a webpage of my project. Here I want to display user selected categories and then want to display its subjects that belong to category. There, users could have more than 1 category and It no problem I can print all those category in my first while loop... but problem is when Im try to print subjects it has only one row as a result.. there are more subjects in each category. can anybody tell me what has happens?

this is my code.... Note: both queries are working properly.. I tried those user mysql client program.

```
    <?php

    require_once ('../../includes/config.inc.php');
    require_once( MYSQL1 );

    $outQuery = "SELECT institute_category.category_id, category_name
            FROM institute_category
            INNER JOIN category ON institute_category.category_id = category.category_id
            WHERE institute_category.institute_id = $instituteId";  

    $outResult = mysqli_query( $dbc, $outQuery);


    while ( $outRow = mysqli_fetch_array ( $outResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC) )   {

        $categoryId = $outRow['category_id']; 
        $category = $outRow['category_name']; 

        echo '<fieldset class="alt">
                <legend><span>Category : <em style="color: red;">' . $category . '</em></span></legend>';



                    $innerQuery = "SELECT category_subject.category_id, category_subject.subject_id, subjects
                            FROM category_subject
                            INNER JOIN category ON category_subject.category_id = category.category_id
                            INNER JOIN subject ON category_subject.subject_id = subject.subject_id
                            WHERE category_subject.category_id = $categoryId";  

                    $innerResult = mysqli_query( $dbc, $innerQuery);

                    $c = $i = 0;

                        echo '<table class="form_table" ><tr>'; 

                                while($innerRow = mysqli_fetch_array( $innerResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC  )){

                                    // if remainder is zero after 2 iterations (for 2 columns) and when $c > 0, end row and start a new row:  
                                    if( ($c % 2) == 0 && $c != 0){
                                        echo "</tr><tr>";
                                    }

                                    echo '<td width="50%"><input type="checkbox" name="subject[]"  value="' . $innerRow['category_id'] . ":" . $category . ":"  . $innerRow['subject_id'] . ":". $innerRow['subjects'] . '" />&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $innerRow['subjects'] . '</td>' . "\n";

                                    $c++; 

                                } // while..
                                    // in case you need to fill a last empty cell:
                                    if ( ( $i % 2 ) != 0 ){

                                    // str_repeat() will be handy when you want more than 2 columns
                                      echo str_repeat( "<td>&nbsp;</td>", ( 2 - ( $i % 2 ) ) );
                                    }
                                echo "</tr></table>";   

    } 

echo '</fieldset>'; 
?>
```

this is my HTML

```
    good<fieldset class='alt'>
<legend><span>Category : <em style='color: red;'>grade 1 - 4</em></span></legend>
    <table class='form_table'><tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='50%'><input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='2:grade 1 - 4:2:Art' />&nbsp;&nbsp;Art</td>
        <td width='50%'><input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='2:grade 1 - 4:3:Art & Craft' />&nbsp;&nbsp;Art & Craft</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='50%'><input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='2:grade 1 - 4:4:Bialogy' />&nbsp;&nbsp;Bialogy</td>
        <td width='50%'><input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='2:grade 1 - 4:5:Buddhism' />&nbsp;&nbsp;Buddhism</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<fieldset class='alt'>
    <legend><span>Category : <em style='color: red;'>grade 5 (scholarship exam)</em></span></legend>
        <table class='form_table'><tr>
            <tr>
            <td width='50%'><input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='3:grade 5 (scholarship exam):1:Agro & Food Technology' />&nbsp;&nbsp;Agro & Food Technology</td>
            <td width='50%'><input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='3:grade 5 (scholarship exam):2:Art' />&nbsp;&nbsp;Art</td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='50%'><input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='3:grade 5 (scholarship exam):3:Art & Craft' />&nbsp;&nbsp;Art & Craft</td>
        <td width='50%'><input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='3:grade 5 (scholarship exam):4:Bialogy' />&nbsp;&nbsp;Bialogy</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
        <fieldset class='alt'>
    <legend><span>Category : <em style='color: red;'>grade 6 - 10</em></span></legend>
        <table class='form_table'><tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='50%'><input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='4:grade 6 - 10:2:Art' />&nbsp;&nbsp;Art</td>
        <td width='50%'><input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='4:grade 6 - 10:3:Art & Craft' />&nbsp;&nbsp;Art & Craft</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='50%'><input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='4:grade 6 - 10:4:Bialogy' />&nbsp;&nbsp;Bialogy</td>
        <td width='50%'><input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='4:grade 6 - 10:5:Buddhism' />&nbsp;&nbsp;Buddhism</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

any comments are greatly appreciated..

thank you

Comment: Could you show the HTML code you get?

Comment: I have added output HTML to my question... see it..

Answer (score 0):

Since you fetch your rows in the inner loop into an associative array, and the key is the `category_id`, every iteration will replace the result of the previous one.  I think you should use `mysqli_fetch_row()` instead.

Comment: I used it.. but not working... now there is a error message... like this.. An error occurred in script 'C:\wamp\www\lanka_institute\edit_profiles\centers\pick_subjects.php' on line 51: mysqli_fetch_row() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Comment: I suppose you still have MYSQLI_ASSOC as second parameter.  Remove it and try again.

Comment: Still same... actually what has happen?????